# Execute a script after every git push

Tags: linux, git, bash

There is a server running and has a git instance on it. I want a script to run everytime a user does git push to the server. I want my script to be executed then git push to continue. 
Any work arounds?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure If you want a scipt to run prior to push or after. So here is my answer for pre-push. But if you want post-push (i.e after push) you have to change the `pre-push` hooks accordingly to check if pushed successfully and then you can do post push thing.

As suggested by @Travis, `git hooks` is the one that you are looking for. So to execute a script pre-push, you have to do is to create a `pre-push` file in the `.git/hooks`. So in this case put your bunch of code in the pre-post script file `.git/hooks/pre-push` and save it. Then make it executable by `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push`. After you done with this successfully you will be able to see the script gets executed each time you do run push command.

PS: Please note that I haven't tested this whole but expected to work in this way.

In Short, assuming you(Linux user) are in the project directory

```
vim .git/hooks/pre-push # then add your code and save the file
                        # Also put the shebang on top to identify the interpreter
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push # make it executable
```

Comment: note: imo, this works for "pre-push" but does not work for "post-push"

Comment: @mchen.ja for post push just change the script name to `post-push`

Comment: what version of git have you been able to successfully test that with? I couldn't get it working on git 2.14.2 (running on macOS).

Comment: @mchen.ja Apparently I was wrong about the post-push hooks. There is no such exists. Its pre-push that will help to achieve where need to check if pushed successfully http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/09/03/git-pre-push/. Will update the answer. Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: That blog can still be found at Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20160407114214/http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/09/03/git-pre-push/

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged this GitHub so I'm assuming that you are referring to public GitHub and not GitHub enterprise.

You cannot run a script "server-side" on GitHub's servers because that would obviously be a massive vulnerability but you can set up a web hook to trigger a script on another server.

Basically whenever someone does a push, a specific URL will be sent data about the push. You can then trigger a script from this. For more information on web hooks, see the [GitHub API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).

Comment: how about git on other server like dokku(docker) which provides git interface like heroku. ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into git hooks:

[8.3 Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

and, another site regarding this technology:

[githooks.com](http://githooks.com)

Comment: How to go about this on git hooks on server side? I want the action to be triggered on server side