# What local file changes when pushing?

Tags: git

Is there a single (or multiple) local file(s) in `.git` that changes always and with 100% certainty, if and only if a push is pushed to the remote branch and is accepted by the remote branch?

In other words, is there a way to add a `post-push` git hook?

---

I can alias something,

```
alias git-push="git push && ./deliver.sh"
```

But that means I have to memorize some additional curly-cue/stutter step at the root loop of my development workflow.  After many days/weeks/months, guaranteed I am typing `git push && ./deliver.sh` with less cognitive effort, but more keystrokes.  Does it ever get faster? No.

In video game terminology, this is the auto-sync with the cloud. Why should my video game workflow be different than my commit work flow? I demand the smoothness in my video games, but not in the domain where the majority of my life is spent? -- But enough motivation.  There ought to be an easy (and portable) way to do this.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? (This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: @torek I would like to trigger my deployment logic whenever I push to master. But I need files I can watch that are unrelated to my local commits, so that I deploy when committing...but on second thought, I can probably get this done by aliasing the git-push command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a script after every git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136541/execute-a-script-after-every-git-push)

Comment: I am pretty sure there is at least a duplicate of this very question, but I can't find it.

Comment: @DaemonPainter and yet, if you go about trying to solve this problem so that it is effortless and stable in the sense of a cooking utensil that can be used comfortably for 8 hours without mistake, it is actually a problem.   I can alias something, but that means I have to memorize some additional curly-cue/stutter step at the root loop of my development workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single file with any such guarantee.

You can get sort of close.  If your Git has a *remote-tracking name* for some branch name, and you use `git push` in a way that asks their Git to update that branch name, and they accept this particular update, the value stored in your remote-tracking name will be updated to match.

By the time you get the answer, however, it may be out of date.  Suppose you have them update branch `xyzzy`, and your remote-tracking information tells you that before you start, it was commit `a123456`.  Your push asks them to change it to store hash ID `b789abc`.  You query your Git, using `git rev-parse origin/xyzzy`, to see what's in it now, and it is now `b789abc`.  So your push request, asking them to change their `xyzzy` to `b789abc`, was successful.  But they might have `c012345` in it by now, because of a third-party push scheduled right behind yours.